# How is it possible that NAT doesn't back translate packets?

Tags: freebsd, firewall, nat, pfsense

I have the following topology

[image]

and from `myhost` I can ping `router2` but can't ping `router1`.

With `tcpdump` I can observe how my pings go and I see that both `router1` and `router2` reply. But only replies from `router2` are appearing in `re2`.

I.e. NAT back translation doesn't work.

Any other traffic also doesn't return.

Is it possible to diagnose the situation, may be with `ipfw` command? Is it possible to see firewall logs in realtime and discover if it blocks the traffic?

## Details

### Experiment 1

```
myhost> ping router1
<Timeout>

pfSense> tcpdump -n -i re1 icmp
<see both requests from pfSense and responses to it>

pfSense> tcpdump -n -i re2 icmp
<see only requests>
```

### Experiment 2

```
myhost> ping router2
<Ok>

pfSense> tcpdump -n -i re3 icmp
<see both requests from pfSense and responses to it>

pfSense> tcpdump -n -i re2 icmp
<see both requests and responses>
```

---

## Update 2

I have 3 ISPs: behind `re0`, `re1` and `re3`. ISPs behind `re1` and `re3` uses their own modems (`router1` and `router2` on the diagram) and ISP behind `re0` is plain twisted pair. `re2` is `LAN`

Routing table

```
> netstat -nr -f inet
default            192.168.100.1      UGS         re3
<DNS1 of provider behind re0>       link#1             UHS         re0
<DNS2 of provider behind re0>       link#1             UHS         re0
<GW of provide behind re0>.0/23     link#1             U           re0
<IP address of re0>.151      link#7             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#7             UH          lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#2             U           re1
192.168.0.2        link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.10.0/24    link#3             U           re2
192.168.10.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.17.0/24    link#11            U        ovpns1
192.168.17.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.18.0/24    link#12            U        ovpns2
192.168.18.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.19.0/24    link#13            U        ovpns3
192.168.19.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.27.0/24    link#14            U        ovpns4
192.168.27.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.29.0/24    link#15            U        ovpns5
192.168.29.1       link#7             UHS         lo0
192.168.100.0/24   link#4             U           re3
192.168.100.2      link#7             UHS         lo0
```

Comment: With `tcpdump` running on which interface can you see that `router2` responds to a ping from `myhost` ?

Comment: When pinging `router2` (which is working) I see them both on `re2` and `re3`. Also I see that IPs are translated, i.e. I see that requests are coming from `pfSense` and returning to `pfSense`. When pinging `router1` (which is not working), I still see both requests and responses on `re1` and also see that IPs are translated

Comment: what is the routing table of pfsense?

Comment: @Vaibhav.c see my update pls

Comment: I don't see re0 in diagram provided but can you try to add a default gateway of re1 above re3 in routing table and see if it can reach router 1. try  ```route add default dev re1```

Comment: `NAT back translation doesn't work` so what are destination addresses of the replies you saw at `re1` and `re3`? Are they not both the same LAN IP of `myhost`? I don't know if it's so different in BSDs, but on Linux tcpdump always gives me the original (non-NAT) addresses. (By always I mean like the In and Out for the original and the In and Out of the reply, for both the source and destination IP, at least in the case of source NAT and corresponding *reverse* DNAT)

Comment: @TomYan I have added details on the diagram; replies destination is `192.168.0.2` and `192.168.100.2` in `re1` and `re3` respectively. I think NAT is configuration dependent, pfSense has all incoming traffic disabled in firewall, so it can return only via `NAT`